# When a month is clicked on it only prints 1 of the rows from database rather than all rows linked to that month

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a calendar on my webpage. When a month is clicked, it should print all data linked to that month. However with the current code I have it does not do this. So for example, if I click on January it will print the first January from the database. However, when I click February it should print the data from February but it prints the second piece of data linked to the month January. I want it to print all data from January when I click January and when I click February it should print all data from February etc.

Below is my HTML:

```
<div class="calander-container">
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">January</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">February</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">March</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">April</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">May</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">June</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">July</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">August</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">September</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">October</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">November</p>
        </div>
        <div class="months">
            <p class="months-text">December</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My PHP:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<div class='rallyPrint'>";
            echo "<h2>" . $row['rallyVenue'] . " in " . $row['month'] . " " . $row['year'] . "</h2>";
            echo "<h4>Event: ". $row['rallyEvent'] . " </h4>";
            echo "<h3>Your Marshall(s): " . $row['rallyMarsh'] . "</h3>";
            echo "<h4>When? ". $row['rallyDate'] . " </h4>";
            echo "<p>" . $row['rallyDesc'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>How much? ". $row['rallyCost'] . " </p>";
            echo "<p>How long? ". $row['rallyNights'] . " Nights</p>";
            echo "<p>Pitch Limit? ". $row['pitchLimit'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>Phone Number: 0". $row['phoneNo'] . " </p>";
            echo "<p>Email: <a href='mailto:". $row['email'] . "'> ". $row['email'] ."</a></p>";
            echo "<p>Please make sure you to contact ". $row['rallyMarsh'] . " for more information.</p>";
            if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
                echo "<a href='' id='". $row['rallyId'] . "' class='trash'>Delete</a>";
            }
            echo "</div><br>";


    }
} else {
    echo "<h2 align='center'>Rallies Currently Not Available!</h2>";
    }
```

My Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('.calander-container').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const months = e.target.closest('.months');
  if (!months) {
    return;
  }
  const thisIndex = [...months.parentElement.children].indexOf(months);
  const rallyPrint = document.querySelectorAll('.rallyPrint');
  rallyPrint.forEach((div) => {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  });
  rallyPrint[thisIndex].style.display = 'block';
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's some flaw in logic...PHP returns several divs with class .rallyPrint, then you set them all to 'none', and just one of them you set to 'block'

And the index you set to block you get from months array, but applies it to rallyPrint elements Gut Knows Why

May be you should add class which represebts month to your .rallyPrint divs and display or hide depends on this class